# How to draw an overlapping curve between two bezier points on existing curve p5.js

Tags: processing, p5.js

I'm using p5.js to draw a bezier curve. I want to draw a shorter, partially overlapping curve in another color. Basically, I want to change the color of the curve in certain places.
I was able to draw the first curve and get two bezier points from the curve, but I can't figure out what control points to use for the new (smaller) curve.

```
bezier(x1,y1,cpx1,cpy1,cpx2,cpy2,x2,y2)
AX = x1
BX = cpx1
CX = cpx2
DX = x2

AY = y1
BY = cpy1
CY = cpy2
DY = y2

let t = 0.68;
let ncX = bezierPoint(AX, BX, CX, DX, t);
let ncY = bezierPoint(AY, BY, CY, DY, t);

let t1 = 0.93;
let ncX1 = bezierPoint(AX, BX, CX, DX, t1);
let ncY1 = bezierPoint(AY, BY, CY, DY, t1);

bezier(ncX,ncY,BX,BY,CX,CY,ncX1,ncY1)
//I tried using the original curve control points, but that didn't work
```

Comment: It is possible to define bezier curves in segments, however, I don't know of any support for this in p5.js. If you really need to implement bezier curves in segments you might take a look at https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/ section 9 discusses splitting curves with Casteljau's algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is P5.bezier(), P5.bezierPoint() and some drawing function (point, ellipse) (Click on canvas to draw color).

```js
let x1 = 500,
 y1 = 250,
 x2 = 0,
 y2 = 125,
 x3 = 0,
 y3 = 125,
 x4 = 500,
 y4 = 0;

let steps = 1000,       //variables needed for color change
    cStep = 250/steps,
    c = cStep;

let clicked = false;
  
function setup(){
 var canvas = createCanvas(500, 250);
 noLoop();
}

function draw(){
 background(50, 50, 100);
 noFill();
 stroke(255);
 bezier(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4);
 stroke(100);
 text('Click', x1/2, y2);
}

mouseClicked = function() {
  if (mouseButton === LEFT) {
    if(clicked){
      clear();
        draw();
    }else{
      for (let i = 0; i <= steps; i++) {
        let t = i / steps;
       stroke(c, 250-c, 0);
          fill(c, 250-c, 0);
          let x = bezierPoint(x1, x2, x3, x4, t);
          let y = bezierPoint(y1, y2, y3, y4, t);
    // to colorize one part of the curve only 
    // you need to check the variable t, e.g.
    // between 0.2 and 0.8
          if(t>0.2 && t<0.8)
            ellipse(x, y, 1, 1)
            c=c+cStep;
      }
    }
    clicked = !clicked;
    c=cStep;
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.2/p5.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to extract a subsection of a Bézier curve between two values of *t*. Do this repeatedly and you can subdivide a Bézier curve into N curves, each of which can be drawn and coloured separately.

This [Javascript library](https://github.com/Pomax/bezierjs) looks suitable (documentation can be found [here](https://pomax.github.io/bezierjs/)) to meet this need.

The relevant methods are `.split(t1,t2)` and `.getLUT(steps)`, which returns a lookup table of point coordinates of a subsection of the original Bézier, between *t1* and *t2*.

Now with Processing, iterate over the coordinate table and call Processing's `line()` method between points to draw the relevant curve section (some sub-division of the original Bézier curve).

Failing that, generate the list of points yourself with Processing's `bezierPoint()` method (note this must be called for X and Y coordinates separately), incrementing t by a value small enough to sample the larger Bézier curve sufficiently. Again, iterate over these points with `line()` to render the subsections.

Your problem has also been addressed (a little more descriptively) on *math.stackexchange* [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1408478/subdividing-a-b%C3%A9zier-curve-into-n-curves).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using de Casteljau's algorithm from [Pomax's Bezier Primer](https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/) section 7.
You can change the color of the curve by changing the color values in stroke according to the value of t. Here I draw the curve red when t < .25

```js
var setup = function(){
  createCanvas(250, 250);
  noLoop();
}

var draw = function(){
  var points = [];
  points[points.length] = new pt(90, 110);
  points[points.length] = new pt(25, 40);
  points[points.length] = new pt(230, 40);
  points[points.length] = new pt(150, 240);
  var t = 1;
  while (t >= 0){
    drawCurve(points, t);
    t-=.001;
    if (t < .25){
     stroke(250,0,0);     
    }
  }
}

function drawCurve(points, t){
  if(points.length==1){
    drawPoint(points[0])
  }
  else {
   var newpoints= [];
    for(i=0; i< points.length-1; i++){
      x = (1-t) * points[i].x + t * points[i+1].x
      y = (1-t) * points[i].y + t * points[i+1].y
      newpoints[i] = new pt(x,y);
    }
    drawCurve(newpoints, t)
   }
}

function pt(x, y){
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}

function drawPoint(p){
  point(p.x, p.y);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.3/p5.js"></script>
```